# How to write to all users appdata folder?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that writes to a file in %username\AppData

```
$path = "c:\program files (x86)\java\jre6"
$user = $env:username

if(test-path $path)
{
    add-content "c:\users\$user\AppData\locallow\sun\java\deployment\deployment.properties" "deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=-Xms512m"
    exit 0
}
elseif(!(test-path $path))
{
    exit 1
}
```

However, I need to run this script as an administrator.  Which means I can't run it for the current user, making the $env:username variable useless.

How can I change this script so that it modifies the AppData of every user on the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a ForEach (alias % used) loop on all the folders found in C:\Users

```
$path = "c:\program files (x86)\java\jre6"
$user = $env:username

if(test-path $path)
{
    GCI C:\Users -Directory | %{add-content "$($_.FullName)\AppData\locallow\sun\java\deployment\deployment.properties" "deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=-Xms512m"
    exit 0
}
elseif(!(test-path $path))
{
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that with default settings, not even administrators have access to the profile of another user. They need to take ownership first (and re-assign permissions after that).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Say what now? I'll admit I didn't sleep well last night, but that doesn't seem right to me. I've been in IT for over half my life and I can't remember having to take ownership of another user's profile to gain access to their files if I login with my admin account unless they went and messed with permissions.

Comment: I receive the error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name Directory".....

Comment: You're using PS v3 or higher right? I thought I saw you say that. If that doesn't work you can do `GCI <path> |?{$_.PSIsContainer} |%{<do stuff>}`

Comment: I just took out the -Directory parameter and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I notice you're adding something to Java's deployment.properties file.  I recently went through this and instead of changing the setting for each user you can move the file to C:\Windows\System32\Sun\Java instead and all users will reference the same file.  Here's [some instructions](http://www.wincert.net/tips/microsoft-windows/3953-how-to-import-java-certificates-to-the-system-store).